# What spacing around colon in function notation?

Tags: formatting

Is there some standard for which spacing is to be preferred in the f: X -> Y notation for a function?

Three possibilities:

```
$f \colon X \to Y$
\\
$f: X \to Y$
\\
$f \mathpunct{:} X \to Y$
```

The respective outputs are shown here:
[image]

Comment: Personally, I use `\colon`.

Answer (score 12):

The TeXbook, Chapter 16, p. 134:

> If you want the `:' character to be treated as a punctuation mark
> instead of as a relation, just call it \colon:
>
> $f:A\to B$
>
> $f\colon A\to B$

Hence there shouldn't be `:`, but `\colon`.